# Quick find item with QComboBox in Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qcombobox

I'm using the QComboBox to let the user select a very large quantity of choices. For the moment the user can type a character and the QComboBox selects the first row with this character, but I feel that it's just not enough.
Is there any thing already done for the user to search directly the item by entering a text?
Thanks

Comment: "Very large quantity" might render the qcombobox unusable, consider using a list view plus search field or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `void QComboBox::setCompleter(QCompleter *completer)`